# Remove black areas in image with alpha, odd result, Python opencv

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, alpha

```
file_name = "alpha_sample.png"
src = cv2.imread(file_name, 1)

tmp = cv2.cvtColor(src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_,alpha = cv2.threshold(tmp,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
b, g, r = cv2.split(src)
rgba = [b,g,r, alpha]
dst = cv2.merge(rgba,4)
#cv2.imshow('funny',dst)
cv2.imwrite("Result.png", dst)
```

I am trying to run this short code sample (credits by User: Srikanth Bhandary). The Input image is an image with two black rectangles at the bottom.

[Input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdICG.png)
[Result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DusU4.png)

I want to make these areas transparent. But the result of the code is the image below. The code seems to divide the image quite random in a transparent an a non transparent part.
Any suggestions?

Regards, Tobias

Comment: Working fine for me with python2 as well as python3 with opencv 3.2. I get 2 transparent triangles at the bottom of image.

Comment: Could there be a difference between .png or .jpg. In different combination I get different results...

Comment: Yes, .png can store 4 channels while .jpg is limited to 3 channels only.